# Blue tooth's curve and integral inequality

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, curves, pi

Well playing with geogebra I have discovered (maybe not) the blue tooth's curve see the picture below :

[image]

It's well define by the function :

$$f(x)=(π x)^{2 (1-π x)}+(π (1-x))^{2 (1-π (1-x))}$$

I want to solve the integral inequality :

$$\frac{(2 + π)}{π (1 + π)}<\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx$$

Well for that I try Taylor series (at $x=0.5$) and Bernoulli's inequality to get a polynomials without success because it's too sharp.

I don't know what other tools I can use for .

If you have an approach or an idea it's welcome !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: **Joke** In fact, the problem is very simple if you prove that the integral is just a bit larger than $\frac{1}{10} \Im\left((20+22 i)^{8/13}\right)$ !! Cheers :-)

Comment: If I may ask, what are you doing in Besançon ? Amitiés :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Well I'm studing maths at my home's parents (Co-vid) waiting to start course at university and you ? Amitiés :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a very difficult problem since

$$\frac{(2 + π)}{π (1 + π)} \approx 0.395167 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)\,dx\approx 0.395543$$ and I do not think that any function approximations could be of any help with a so tiny difference.

Avoiding numerical integration, I built an interpolation function for the integrand and, itegrating, got the same result.

May be, you could try with spline functions.

Comment: Mouarf i was not thinking it was so hard (sorry) . Anyway thanks Claude !

Comment: @BiggusDickusPython. You interesting function will look much better if $x$ and $y$ scales are the same. I am still working the problem. ARe you able to use spline functions ? This would be funny. Cheers.

Comment: Well you are too smart for me and I think we need a doctor for this tooth .Bonne journée Claude .